# Android: getArguments() in Fragment returns null, even though I setArguments() inside newInstance()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to pass arguments to my `PopularMoviesFragment` using `newInstance()` method. I have `MainActivity` where inside `onOptionsItemSelected()` I create a fragment using `PopularMoviesFragment.newInstance("popularity.desc")` and then make a transaction.

Inside the `PopularMoviesFragment`: I set arguments `newInstance(String sortBy)` using `setArguments()`, but when I want to retrieve them inside `onCreate()`, `getArguments()` returns null.

Here is the code, `PopularMoviesFragment`:

```
public class PopularMoviesFragment extends Fragment {


  public static PopularMoviesFragment newInstance(String sortBy) {
      PopularMoviesFragment fragment = new PopularMoviesFragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString("sortBy", sortBy);
      fragment.setArguments(args);
      return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      String sortBy = getArguments().getString("sortBy", ""); 
      
      // java.lang.NullPointerException in the previous line
      // Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String 
      // android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' 
      // on a null object reference
  }
}
```

And inside `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_popular_movies:
            PopularMoviesFragment fragment = PopularMoviesFragment.newInstance("popularity.desc");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried the pasted code. It's weird that I didn't get the NullPointerException at all.**

TestActivity.java :

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Button btn_test = findViewById(R.id.btn_test);

        btn_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                testFragment();
            }
        });

    }

    private void testFragment() {
        PopularMoviesFragment fragment = PopularMoviesFragment.newInstance("popularity.desc");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

activity_test.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/btn_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

PopularMoviesFragment.java:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class PopularMoviesFragment extends Fragment {


    public static PopularMoviesFragment newInstance(String sortBy) {
        PopularMoviesFragment fragment = new PopularMoviesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("sortBy", sortBy);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String sortBy = getArguments().getString("sortBy", "");

        Log.i("test", "sortBy=" + sortBy);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for checking that. It didn't solve my problem necessarily, but it definitely helped me to understand the problem was somewhere else. So, the reason for NullPointer was that I had another call to FragmentManager where I replace the container by the same PopularMoviesFragment object, but created via constructor, not a newInstance() method. So it caused NullPointerException. Thanks for your time, I'll accept your answer as it was the most helpful one.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onActivityCreated()` method in your Fragment and retrieve the value of sortBy in this method using this line - `String sortBy = getArguments().getString("sortBy", "");`  instead of the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. This leads to the same NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference